# System Reboot while installing applications using DSC scripts

Tags: visual-c++, windows-installer, reboot, dsc

I have two MSI's that behave differently when installed using DSC scripts.
Both are VC++ applications.
One of the application, after the installation is complete, requests for a reboot, while the other does not.
I have cross verified both vdproj files of these applications.
Neither of the vdproj file has a REBOOT property that could cause a reboot.

I'm wondering what could be the cause of a reboot?

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe this is a symptom of DSC.  I believe it may be the dependencies of each dll.  If you see, the question "*Why is Windows Installer prompting for a reboot?*" on this blog: [MSDN Blog on Installer](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windows_installer_team/archive/2005/09/19/470980.aspx), you'll see the answer, "Windows Installer may prompt for a reboot if it installs over a file that is in use or the package explicitly requests that the installer reboot."

The also give you triage steps in this article.  Lastly, to triage, I'd manually run installers on the VM (independently from DSC).  To see if you can mimic the behavior.

Comment: I'll just add that it all non-deterministic anyway! Anyone that wants to know should do the install with a verbose log and look for things like files-in-use messages and other entries related to reboot.